# Laravel production app, is faker and phpUnit in require-dev for a real reason?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-9, zoho, faker

I always notice that faker and phpunit are in require-dev by default and i'd like a cron job to run tests on production to ensure a certain api connection is stable.

Its a long story so to keep the context as short as possible - we had to establish a connection to our Zoho CRM so we could download data to run operations against.. because zoho sucks for batch file processing and we do a lot of bulk csv file uploads and processing for client information.. and we are gradually building our own custom CRM to get away from Zoho. To do this, I have to rely on this package I found and forked that wraps their official api. https://github.com/asciisd/zoho-v3

For some ungodly reason there are inconsistencies between how the api behaves from local to production environments, sometimes asking for an object, and sometimes expecting a string, etc. Even worse, randomly it switch up the expected attribute type at a random time.

While i was developing this locally, i have a set of unit tests that generate fake data to send up to my admin-only test records then fetch that data and ensure i am pushing/pulling correctly. I would run this manually daily

I just spent a day fixing an error because of one of these situations and i really want to set up a cron that will run these tests daily on production for me. Is there any real reason why faker/phpunit is not by default in the standard require section of composer in Laravel? are there security concerns?

Answer (score 1):

`PHPUnit` and `Faker` are not on `require-dev` because you should never run tests on production. There is no "excuse" or however you want to call it, to move it to `require` and run tests in there. `Faker` could be moved to `require`, it is most of the time used in tests, but since Laravel 10.x, you have `fake()` helper available, so you could move it to `require`, I would personally never use Faker in production, unless you have a very specific and good case where it could help you, usually there is no good case. I do think we have `phpunit` in `require-dev` due to standards, as simple as that, because you can definitely move it to `require` (production).

Why? Imagine you do a deploy, but someone forgots to only run the tests you are wanting to run, you could potentially run ALL your tests... in a PRODUCTION database, imagine what type of catastrophic disaster that one could be for the company?

There are a range of solutions you could approach, but depends on how you are testing it, and more specifically, if the API has some whitelisting you should consider or anything similar, limiting what machine (IP) could communicate with this external API:

1. Have a cron do a specific HTTP request (REST) to the API, if only one call sufices, that's it. If it fails, report it with an error tracker or similar.
2. If you have to test a lots of endpoints (or cases for an endpoint), so a test is really the solution, and you have no constraints as I said before (no whitelisting), then you can have an external CI/CD service, like circleci.com, GitHub Actions, Bitbucket Pipelines, and more services, to run these tests in a schedule way (you can do that), so they are in another environment that is not production.
3. If you do have constraints, but you can still whitelist more machines (IPs), you should read the external CI/CD service documentation or contact them, asking if you can get a fixed IP for a test runner or similar, so you whitelist that worker when it runs the tests.
4. Following *2.* and *3.*, in a company I used to work, we did have Bamboo (it is a CI/CD solution from Atlassian, more complex or broad than Bitbucket Pipelines), we had a button on a workflow that, when clicked, it would also run these tests. When would we have this button and behaviour available? When we were running a CI pipeline on any branch (running tests on any branch because you commited), so if you also wanted to run those external endpoint tests (integration tests), you could do it at that moment.
5. If you cannot whitelist another machine or it is way more complex to whitelist another machine, I would be very very VERY carefull to triple check the command you are writting on the scheduler to run the tests, if you or anyone changes anything on the calling command and run another tests that could mess real data, you are done for some time... (or worse if you have no automatic DB snapshots)

I may be missing another solutions, but that is what it is comming to my mind right now (and based on what you wrote).

Hope it helps, else add more info please!

Comment: heard thank you, it makes sense that its basically a failsafe protecting running tests against prod databases..

unfortunately this api's dependency keeps me stuck at Laravel 9.x for now. The goal is to move this entire database onto our own custom CRM so eventually we'll be able to drop zoho all together